# TailwindCSS: restrict background color to specific colors from palette

Tags: tailwind-css

The designers are like:

> Hey, here's the color palette for our app: **`red`**, `green`, **`blue`**, `blue-light`, **`blue-dark`**

and then

> But the background colors can only be of these colors: **`red`, `blue`, `blue-dark`**. We explicitly disallow using `blue-light` for backgrounds because of accessibility requirements. Can you also please enforce it in ... what did you call it again? *BacktyphoonCSS*?

Tailwind allows you to completely overwrite the default color palette. That way, you can ensure developers won't use colors from outside the allowed ones. This is described [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#background-colors):

> By default, Tailwind makes the entire default color palette available as background colors.
>
> You can customize your color palette by editing the theme.colors variable in your >tailwind.config.js file, or customize just your background colors using the >theme.backgroundColor section of your Tailwind config.

So I added my palette first:

```js
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: theme => ({
      red: '#ff0000',
      green: '#00ff00',
      blue: {
        light: '#0000f0',
        DEFAULT: '#0000fa',
        dark: '#0000ff',
      },
    }),
  },
}
```

This works and I can set the background colors to the colors from the palette. But now, I have a problem because of this line from above:

> **By default, Tailwind makes the entire default color palette available as background colors.**

So writing `<div class="bg-blue-light">` will infact work, but the designers won't use blue-light for bgcolor in the design system, so I also want it to be impossible to set it as bgcolor. How do I restrict Tailwind background color to just certain colors from the palette?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to reference colors already defined in the palette. You can use these base colors to create a separate "backgroundColors" palette.

I came up with this:

```js
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: theme => ({
      red: '#ff0000',
      green: '#00ff00',
      blue: {
        light: '#0000f0',
        DEFAULT: '#0000fa',
        dark: '#0000ff',
      },
    }),
    backgroundColor: theme => ({
      //get the value from the color definitions above (7th line from top)
      red: theme('colors.red'),
      blue: {
        DEFAULT: theme('colors.blue.DEFAULT'),
        dark: theme('colors.blue.dark'),
      }
    }),
  },
}
```

This works - `<div style="bg-blue-light" />` no longer sets a background color. It's a shame you need to rebuild the `{DEFUALT: ..., light: ...}` objects from scratch and how much duplication it introduces.